# Lendo a porta serial em tempo real em csharp

Tags: c#

Estou tentando realizar um controle onde recebo informações enviadas pelo *Arduino*.

Essas informações são do tipo *string* e de formato `VX1.987`ou `VY0.123` e são enviadas em alta velocidade. Após serem filtradas e tratadas, atualizam as *textbox* no meu programa, e dessa forma o que vejo na *textbox* é a ultima informação recebida.

O que acontece com o meu código é que em um determinado ponto, por ex, foram enviados **1000** linhas pelo *Arduino*, o meu programa vai atualizando até **600** e depois para de mostrar as atualizações. Sei que no *buffer* de recepção estão as outras **400** linhas, mas **não foram mostradas**.

Procurei na internet e eu vi muitos comandos mas não consegui alinhar com a minha necessidade.

```cs
namespace ControleCaseiro
    {
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         serialPort1.DataReceived += new    SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
        } 

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {                   
                    DataIn = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(MostraDados));                
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            { }
        }

     private void MostraDados(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        switch (DataIn)
            {
                case "19\r":
                    textcontrole.Text = "XOFF";
                    break;
                case "17\r":
                     textcontrole.Text = "XON";
                    if (botãoEnviaGcode)
                    {
                        LinhaArquivo++;
                        EnviaGcode();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    FiltroDadosRecebidos(DataIn);                 
                     break;
            }      
      }

    private void FiltroDadosRecebidos(string valorRecebido)
     {        
        string eixo="";
        int tamanho=0;
        string valorEixoAtual="";
        if (valorRecebido.Length > 1)
            {               
                    tamanho = valorRecebido.Length;           
                     eixo = valorRecebido.Substring(0, 2);                   
            switch (eixo)
               {                             
                  case "VX":
                              valorEixoAtual = valorRecebido.Substring(2, tamanho - 3);           
                              txtPosAtualX.Text=valorEixoAtual;
                              break;
                  case "VY":
                              valorEixoAtual = valorRecebido.Substring(2, tamanho - 3);
                              txtPosAtualY.Text=valorEixoAtual;
                              break;
                  case "VZ":
                              valorEixoAtual = valorRecebido.Substring(2, tamanho - 3);
                              txtPosAtualZ.Text=valorEixoAtual;
                              break;
                   default :
                              DadosRecebidos.Items.Add(DataIn);// se não for dados referentes aos eixos, vai mostrar na listbox “DadosRecebidos”
                              break;
               }

            }                     

        }
    }
```